# Error building mono-6.12.0.199 on Solaris 11 x86

Tags: mono

When I try to build mono 6.12.0.199 from the sources, it fails due to a missing makefile dependency.

I downloaded the source for mono-6.12.0.199 from mono-project.com and used ./autogen.sh amd64-pc-solaris2.11 followed by make get-monolite-latest then make.  All seemed to be going fine until the following message:

make[4]: *** No rule to make target '../../mono/metadata/libmonoruntime-static.la', needed by 'mono-dtrace.o'.  Stop.

Has anyone else encountered this kind of error when trying to build mono?  Is there a different version of the source I should be trying?  This one claims to be a stable release version.

UPDATE:

Using the following seems to eliminate the problems and allow the make to continue running:

./configure --disable-dtrace

However, the following error now occurs:

`CCLD     mono-boehm Undefined                       first referenced symbol                             in file mono_threads_platform_get_stack_bounds ../../mono/utils/.libs/libmonoutils.a(libmonoutils_la-mono-threads.o) mono_w32file_get_file_system_type   ../../mono/metadata/.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-icall.o) ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[4]: *** [Makefile:1770: mono-boehm] Error 1`

Comment: The Mono project had big changes in the past and is heading to the direction of unknown (likely a sad end https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/). So, if you do want a feasible way out, .NET Core might be a better option on the table.